# Can Logitech MK220 wireless keyboard and mouse can be used on the Pi Model A+ as supplied?

Tags: pi-a+

Can anybody please tell me whether the Logitech MK220 wireless keyboard and mouse can be used on the Pi Model A+ as is (ie. using just the one supplied USB port)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I have the Logitech mk 550  keyboard and it works fine out of the box, although certain keys like media control didn't work for me.